# Despite thousands of impressions and page views, Google Adsense is not registering any clicks

Tags: google-adsense, click-tracking

I have a website Panpact.com and it has Google AdSense ads on it. A few months ago I posted an article on my page which got over ten thousand views. The impressions and views registered with AdSense but not a single click.

According to statcounter I did get lots of clicks but I know this is unreliable. Still you would think I would get at least one or two clicks. I posted another article yesterday and it has nearly one thousand views but still no clicks. I don't think AdSense is registering them.

What should I do? If it matters I used to get clicks back in 2016 where my site had a different name but I changed it and I hadn't noticed clicks since.

Comment: Have you signed new name of your website into Google AdSense ?

Comment: How do I do that and what do u mean?

Comment: In Google AdSense go to Settings -> My Sites -> And click the big + (plus) in the right top corner to add the website. Google may think that the clicks come on the older website and that might be the problem

Comment: It's already there and verified

Comment: Do you use GA (Google Analytics)? You should try GA instead of StatCounter. Google AdSense and GA can be linked together so it might create less confusion in your data.

Comment: I have linked google analytics admit has more or less the same data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56862/discussion-between-jakub-klisky-and-user2279603).

Comment: I can't continue in chat I need at least 20 reputation

Comment: Statcounter sees the exit links but it also sees the mount of vies and 0 clicks with ten thousand visitors is highly irregular

Comment: exit links don't mean that user clicked on the ad, it can be that the user closed your website or clicked on some anchor on your website...anyway, that view/click ratio is wierd

Comment: In Google AdSense do you have 10k views or 10k impressions ?

Comment: It says exit link Adsense 320x160 but it doesn't matter anyway I'm going to switch to Amazon ads. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: 12k views 16k impressions

Comment: If you have 10k views and not 10k impressions it doesn't have to be low impression/ratio because you can set the ad balance (so in some cases the ad wasn't shown even if the user was on the page).Then you could have 10k views but much lower impressions and when user doesn't see the ad he won't click it

Comment: Did you have some problems with self-clicking ads ?

Comment: It's possible no one is interested in the ads on your site. I'm sorry if that's a harsh statement but people online can click what they want. You might want to follow google's advice on placement of ads and make sure you don't violate their policies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen Google AdSense not count clicks when they happen.  If you are getting impressions in AdSense and you see ads on your site yourself, it is probably installed correctly.   Users are likely just not clicking on the ads.

The problem is likely your ad placement.   When I visit your site, I only see a small add above all the content:

[image]

Ads in that position are routinely ignored by everybody.   To get users to see ads, they need to be in more visible locations.

- In between paragraphs of articles
- In the main column but to the right or left of content
- Just beneath the content (great for articles because often users are willing to click on an ad when they are done reading)

Take a look at the "Show off your content" section of [Google ad placement best practices](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1282097?hl=en).   Here are some of their suggested layouts:

[image] [image]

They also have a lot of advice about what NOT to do.